# Lenova Thinkpad power button does nothing

Tags: power-management, thinkpad, button

I have installed Ubuntu on many computers, both desktop and laptop, and the power button opens the power menu asking what to do. However, I just got a Lenova Thinkpad T410i secondhand from a friend. Overall, this machine is very compatible with Ubuntu. But for some reason, the power button does nothing. Of course, I can just use the power menu in the upper right hand corner. But the power menu that comes up when one presses and releases the power button is something that I really love (mostly because it doesn't happen in Windows!).

Does anyone know how I can get it to work? I've tried xbindkeys (and use it to assign other keyboard shortcuts) but the power button is not detected as a key. FYI I'm running 14.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and answer my own question, and hopefully this will help someone! 
Well, it turns out that if you hold down the power button for around a second, the menu comes up!

Comment: That's surprising)